# How to fix a 'foreign key constraint fails' in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting a simple CRUD in PHP, i have created a two tables in phpmyadmin one for personal info (name, last name, email, phone), the other for additional phone numbers. I have a problem with setting the foreign key to connect the two tables. The additional phone number is dynamically added from the user with help of jQuery (it can be called upon or not depending if the user has or hasn't two phone numbers). 
Can someone point our where i am making the mistake. 
My knowledge of PHP is limited, and i create tables and databases from the GUI of phpmyadmin not with code.

The code that enters the added form input in the database.

```
// Checks if the submit button has been pressed, setst the variable values of the name values from the form
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO personal (first_name, last_name, email, phone_number) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone_number')")
      OR die($mysqli->error);
}
```

```
// Checks if the Add more numbers button has been pressed
 if (isset($_POST['phone_number2'])) {
   $phone_number2 = $_POST['phone_number2'];
// foreach statement to loop trought the array of inserted additional phone numbers
  foreach ($phone_number2 as $key => $value) {
      $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO phone (phone_number2) VALUES('$value')")
               OR die($mysqli->error);
}
}
```

Up until the point i enter the foreign key it works, and after i enter it i get the error.
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exercise`.`phone`, CONSTRAINT `phone_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `personal` (`user_id`))

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Your `phone` table has a `user_id` field that must reference a `user_id` from the `personal` table; it's not going to magically know which one to use when you omit it from inserts into the `phone` table.

Comment: You need to SET the key field in `phone` to the key used in `personal`

Comment: first_name := `Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --`

Comment: @spencer7593 Luckily he didn't call `$mysqli->multi_query()`, so that won't drop anything.

Comment: Luckily no one with last_name := `O'Reilly`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$mysqli->insert_id` to get the ID of the user that was added in the previous query, and use that as the foreign key in the `phone` table.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO personal (first_name, last_name, email, phone_number) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone_number')")
        OR die($mysqli->error);
    $userid = $mysqli->insert_id;
// Checks if the Add more numbers button has been pressed
    if (isset($_POST['phone_number2'])) {
        $phone_number2 = $_POST['phone_number2'];
// foreach statement to loop trought the array of inserted additional phone numbers
        foreach ($phone_number2 as $key => $value) {
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO phone (userid, phone_number2) VALUES($userid, '$value')")
                OR die($mysqli->error);
        }
    }
}
```